# Django REST Framework Filtering

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using [Django REST Framework Generic Filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering) and wish to accomplish two goals:

1. Get only the last result of a queryset. For example, http://my_server/users/?last will return only the last user (the one with the greatest id).
2. Get the number of results in a query set. For example, http://my_server/users/?category=admin&count will return the **number** of admin users.

What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last` is effectively an alias for the desired ID. It doesn't make sense to use a query param here, since your url structure already allows to retrieve individual objects by id. Overriding `get_object()` would allow you to use `/api/users/last`.

```py
def get_object(self):
    lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
    lookup = self.kwargs.get(lookup_url_kwarg, None)

    if lookup == 'last':
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        return queryset.order_by('pk').last()

    return super(UserViewSet, self).get_object()
```

---

For the count of all users, as mentioned, pagination is a builtin way for you to get that number. If you don't want to use pagination, you can also use `list_route()`s and `detail_route()`s for custom actions or routes. The below adds a `/api/users/count` route.

```py
@list_route(methods=['get'])
def count(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    return Response({'count': queryset.count()})
```

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a custom subclass of `rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend`. They define a `filter_queryset` method to perform the filtering, for example:

```
from rest_framework import filters

from .models import User

class UserFilter(filters.DjangoFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        if 'last' in request.QUERY_PARAMS:
            queryset = User.objects.filter(pk=queryset.last().pk)
        # pass it up for the built-in / other filters
        return super(UserFilter, self).filter_queryset(
            request, queryset, view
        )
```

Then in your `UserViewSet`, have:

```
# ...
serializer_class = UserSerializer
filter_backends = (UserFilter,)
# ...
```

As for showing the count, I'd advise looking at the [Django rest framework pagination docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/). With it set up, it will automatically put `next`, `previous`, `count`, and `results` values into your JSON returned to the user.